# fprintf and ofstream using without opening file

Tags: c++, c

Can i safely use code like

```
fprintf(nullptr, "str");
```

or smth like

```
std::ofstream() << "str";
```

and

```
std::ofstream f;
f << "str";
```

Is there any descriptions of such situations in the C / C++ Standards?

Comment: What would this achieve?

Comment: I need this to throw away many errors in GCC like
warning: unused parameter 'args#0' [-Wunused-parameter]

Comment: to "unuse" an parameter just use it by something useless, eg. `typedef char bla[sizeof arg];`

Comment: But please, ask the questions that interest you in the first place, not questions that come up in solving them with some hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using C++ streams the output operations have no effect when they are sent to stream with `std::ios_base::failbit` or `std::ios_base::badbit` set. If it is acceptable that the stream doesn't indicate success, you can just create an `std::ostream` with a null stream buffer:

```
std::ostream nullstream(0);
```

If you want the stream to also indicate success, you can just use it with a stream buffer indicating success from `overflow()` and `sync()` but not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question you asked, but the one you should have asked - you can assign attributes like `unused` to variables in GCC, which will suppress warnings.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html